# Undesired Whitespace Between Start of Subsection and Start of Text

Tags: margins, overleaf, white-space

After changing my margin size from 1in to 0.5in, an large bit of whitespace apppeared after the title for the first section of my article. How can I prevent this large amount of whitespace from appearing? I am writing the article using overleaf.

Here is what it looks like with `\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}`

[image]

Here it what it looks like with `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}`
[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Latex tries to create a balanced layout. From a birds eyes view your problem arises from using too many words and characters. An unconventional way is to prune your text, e.g. abstract, first paragraph and 2nd section title. You may also improve readability from doing so as a nice side effect. // I like your screenshots. Next time it will be better to copy your code, as well.

Comment: The reason: There's not enough space at the bottom of column 1 to fit in the title of section 2 and a least one line of text, since a sectional unit it bound to the first line of text.

Comment: The question: What are you willing to change to avoid this situation. Margins?  Interline spaces?  Paragraph skips?  Abstract  content? Introduction content?  Font size? Maybe simplify section title to "The current State" as the topic is obvious? Only you can decide what could be an acceptable  change,

Comment: @Werner Thank you for spotting that! I changed the title to "The Current State of Predicting DTBA." Does not look as nice but it does clear up the elephant in the room. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind the big gap stems from the fact that sectional units are bound to the first line of the paragraph following it. Otherwise, it would be weird to have a sectional unit at the bottom of a page, just sitting there on its own. This forced connection implies that when there's not enough room left on the page, the sectional unit is pushed to the following page.

In your two-column setup, these "pages" also apply to columns. Now it should be clear to see that there's not enough room to fit the heading (**2 The Current State of Drug-Target Binding Affinity Prediction**) and the first line ("A variety of computational methods, ...") at the bottom of column one.

The best possible solution here is to restructure your text. Either add some content to the introduction, or reduce the content within the sectional title.